# invitation friends api facebook

Tags: facebook, api, invite

```
Please help me with this problem.
```

I can´t receive the invite. But i can send the invitiation.
What´s happening?

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId:'APP_ID',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});
```

I have this code in my FanPage after the like...

```
function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Your Message diaolog'
});
}
</script>


//HTML Code
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 
Facebook Invite Friends Link
</a>
```

please help please.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to handle the requestCallback in the FB.ui call, like this:

```
         ...
            FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
                message: 'My Great Request'
            }, requestCallback);
         ...

        function requestCallback(result) {
            // Handle callback here
        }
```

It is all I can help you because I'm totally newbie with FB API but I'm looking into it little by little.

PS. I guess that in FB.init you wrote 'APP_ID' to hide the real app id... if not you have to write you own app id from your app :P